# Getting Top 20 checked in cities in the world

Tags: api, geolocation, foursquare, location-based-service

Is there any way using foursquare api or some other location based api to get top say 20 checked-in cities in the world? I know we don't check-in to cities but I am trying to get a list of top 20 cities or states in the world which generated most of the check-in data for the day.

Comment: Will these guys - @Cody-Gray, Eric-J, martin-clayton, Jason-Hall, Graviton explain to me why they have closed my question and gave me down vote? It was a very legit question and a valid scenario on which I am working. Please think before you try to impose your SO reputation power on someone else. Don't act like a hitler.

Comment: Questions are automatically downvoted by the system when they get closed as "off topic". And yes, this is off topic because it's not programming-related.

Comment: That's nonsense. It's absolutely programming related. There's a foursquare tag on stackoverflow and he's asking about how to use the foursquare api. As one of the developers of the foursquare java api.. I'm offended.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I think those guys are out of their minds. Their stupidity has eaten away four points from my reputation score. As per their logic [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248/whats-a-good-free-and-open-source-asp-net-ecommerce-solution) topic should also be closed but it is pretty much active because they did not visited it. I have already written to SO for their unacceptable act. Please have a look @Code-Gray

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I think these folks have nothing better to do than go around and down vote things without actually READING the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with foursquare anyway... although you could make a series of calls based on the lat/long centerpoints of major cities and get top trending venues for each.